# How to retrieve text from wx python CtrlText?

Tags: wxpython, textctrl

I'm trying to retrieve a text value from a TextCtrl object in Python, and I can't seem to get it.
The text is named "text" in the code below, I tried to retrieve the value in "Click" function.
I understood well how to show the text box and button and how to retrieve the event, but when I run this code, I have an error that says that "myForm" has no attribute "text", How to set "text" as an attribute to myForm? How to get the value from the text object?

```
from datetime import datetime, time
from pygame import mixer # Load the required library
import wx


class myForm(wx.Frame):


    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(myForm, self).__init__(parent,title=title, size=(300, 100))

        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        fgs = wx.FlexGridSizer(3, 2, 9, 25)
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        title = wx.StaticText(panel, label="Time in second")

        button1 = wx.Button(panel, label="Start")
        text=wx.TextCtrl(panel)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Click)
        fgs.AddMany([(title), (text, 1, wx.EXPAND),(button1,1,wx.EXPAND)])

        fgs.AddGrowableRow(2, 1)
        fgs.AddGrowableCol(1, 1)

        hbox.Add(fgs, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, border=15)
        panel.SetSizer(hbox)

        self.Centre()
        self.Show()  


    def Click(self, event):
        print 'event reached frame class'
        #print tc1.GetValue()
        print "value",self.text.GetValue()
        event.Skip()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the text control into an attribute of your frame's class. So instead of creating it like this:

```
text = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
```

You need to do this:

```
self.text = wx.TextCtrl(panel)
```

Note that `text` is not the same as `self.text`.

Now your event handler will work.